# Android Wear: Creating Lists trouble

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am fairly new to Android and completely new to Android Wear development. Ultimately, my goal is to dynamically create a list of 10 items. Each item will have an Image and a TextView. I am trying to implement the example given here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html . The only things I have changed in this example is that in the res/layout/list_item.xml file: the ImageView has no src. Instead, I set the background color to a hash value. I also change the TextView.textColor to a hash value.

Everything compiles fine and I am able to install the app onto my Moto 360, via bluetooth. However, when I open the app on my Moto 360, an error message appears "Unfortunately, myApp has stopped." All I know is that if I comment out this line:

```
listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, elements));
```

in the WearActivity.onCreate method, then the error does not appear, but now the content of the app is blank. Any help would be great! Thank you.

EDIT: Logcat

```
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
--------- beginning of main
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.wearable.init.InitializeGmsWearableReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/GCM     ( 1994): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android
.gms.INITIALIZE
D/AuthorizationBluetoothService( 1994): Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be
.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher(29720): Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.
stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService$Receiver
I/EventLogService(29720): Aggregate from 1437604524915 (log), 1437604524915 (data)
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
E/StreamVibrator( 1911): Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService$Receiver
I/EventLogService(29720): Aggregate from 1437606510039 (log), 1437606510039 (data)
I/GoogleURLConnFactory( 1994): Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
I/GoogleURLConnFactory( 1994): Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
W/Uploader( 1994): No account for auth token provided
I/art     (29720): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 17.730ms for cause DisableMovingGc
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/ClockworkProxy( 1911): doAccept: Create socket stream 5 for TCP connection from /192.168.167.239:54729 to /74.125.25.95:443
D/ClockworkProxy( 1911): doAccept: rpc succeeded. Activate stream 5
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
E/StreamVibrator( 1911): Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/SensorHAL( 1785): adjustSensorHandle: handle = 10 adjustedHandle = 1
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService$Receiver
I/EventLogService(29720): Aggregate from 1437608311873 (log), 1437608311873 (data)
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/art     ( 1785): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 31045(2046KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 1.708ms total 103.118ms
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
E/StreamVibrator( 1911): Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService$Receiver
I/EventLogService(29720): Aggregate from 1437610113756 (log), 1437610113756 (data)
I/GoogleURLConnFactory( 1994): Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
D/SensorHAL( 1785): adjustSensorHandle: handle = 10 adjustedHandle = 1
E/StreamVibrator( 1911): Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.motorola.targetnotif/com.motorola.omni.NotificationAlarmReceiver
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/StreamVibrator( 1911): Found notifications that tried to vibrate, but they never made it to the top of the stream. Not vibrating.
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
E/libsuspend( 1785): Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService$Receiver
I/EventLogService(29720): Aggregate from 1437611998899 (log), 1437611998899 (data)
I/ActivityManager( 1785): Resuming delayed broadcast
W/bt-btif ( 2231): dm_pm_timer expires 0
W/bt-btif ( 2231): proc dm_pm_timer expires
```

Comment: It is always very useful to look at the log and take a note of the exception that is thrown; both for yourself and for posting here when you run into such issue.

Comment: The LogCat is empty. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: The only thing I can see is under the Debug/Debugger tab, under variables, it says "Frame is not available"..... I don't really know what this is referring to though

Comment: Logcat is what I want but it can't be empty, believe me :-)  From a command line, do "adb -e logcat" (assuming that moto 360 is the only device connected over tcp/ip) and see what will be written there when you get that error. Might be easier to debug in an emulator if you can reproduce it there (working with adb over BT is a pain)

Comment: I have added some of what the logcat has produced, above. :)

Comment: I tried using emulators, but they wouldn't work for me...... It was easier to start debugging on an actual device than trying to solve the emulator problem :P

Comment: There is no exception in that log; when you get "Unfortunately myApp has stopped" dialog, there will be a stack trace in the logcat and that is the key to see what is killing your app.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to filter out the logs so that I only see logs from myApp? I have scattered my code with: Log.d("myLogTag","message"); but the only thing printing out is my mainActivity.onCreate method. I tried putting a try/catch around the contents of the onCreate method, but no exception is being thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: you can do "adb -e logcat | grep myLogTag"

Comment: I tracked down the error. It's in the function onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) on the .inflate() function call. The error says: "Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.android.support.wearable.notifications.WearableListItemLayout"

Comment: I fixed the error. I just needed to change the beginning and ending tag of the list_item.xml. Thanks for all of your help, couldn't have done it without you :D

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I've posted the solution and accepted it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As requested, here is the coded solution:

```
<!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>-->
<com.my.app.WearableListItemLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ID1"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ID2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:textColor="#000003"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <!--android:drawableTop="@drawable/myImage"/>-->
            <!--android:drawablePadding="2dp"/>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</com.my.app.WearableListItemLayout>
```